# How to combine and minify Javascript files on per page basis using Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

The entire project contains 40+ JavaScript files.

However, a single page requires only four script files on an average.

Of these four files, 
2 are common across all pages. Lets call them `a.js` and `b.js`
and 2 are unique to each page. Lets call them `x1.js, x2.js, x3.js...` and `y1.js, y2.js, y3.js...`

I want grunt to do the following:

- Combine & Minify a.js and b.js to c.js. Replace `a.js` & `b.js`
  references with`c.js` in all HTML files
- Combine & Minify x1.js and y1.js to z1.js. Replace `x1.js` & `y1.js` 
  references to `z1.js` in all HTML files
- Combine & Minify x2.js and y2.js to z2.js. Replace `x2.js` & `y2.js` 
  references to `z2.js` in all HTML files
- And so on...

Edit:
I noticed that angular loads javascript and css files linked from views, using XMLHTTPRequest. As far as I know most browsers would disregard the caching headers for AJAX requests. So unless there is a way to make the browser use cached for view specific resource, each load of the view will necessitate downloading those files again.

Comment: It might help to have a directory for each set of JavaScript files that are going to be combined.

Comment: use https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin